# JS if button was clicked, not possbile to click again until event happens

Tags: javascript, events, button, direction

I am wondering how to establish a function with JS. I am making a snake game and have created movement so far. Through buttons I can navigate the snake itself. However if I click same buttion several times in sequence, the speed increases of the snake because of SpeedX += 5; function is performed.

I am wondering how to prevent this. I thought about an event or function that prevents clicking same direction more than one time in sequence until direction is changed. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Use a flag like `var clicked = true`; and check in the click event if `clicked` is already set to true and exit function if so. Reset the `clicked` flag in the related event.

Comment: why are you incrementing the Speed variables `SpeedX += 5` couldn't you just set it to `SpeedX = 5` then you wont have any unwanted acceleration.

Comment: @synthet1c Maybe the button is supposed to increase the speed, but you have to do other things in between.

Comment: Hey cytzix, It would be useful if you could post a snippet of the code you currently have that illustrates the problem so that we can give you more specific feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply disable the button by setting `diabled` to true after it has been clicked. After that, just re-enable the other buttons. Here is minimal example : https://jsfiddle.net/61q8kucr/.